# Add two lines and get an animal

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Add two straight lines in the picture below and get an animal. Please explain your answer.

Note: Every part of the drawing below must be part of your answer.

[image]

Hint:

> It becomes a Rebus word after you add 2 lines

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The animal could be:

> FELINE, a "cat or member of the cat family"
>
>  [image: f e line]
>  Explanation:  F + E + LINE

Comment: Excellent @Amoz. I am glad I held back on giving another hint.

Answer (score 10):

Added lines in red:

> [image: CIC, add A]

Explanation:

> CIC, add A

Answer (score 5):

With the addition of two relatively long lines, we see

> a close-up cartoon of a hedgehog, deprived of all but one of its spines in a tragic accident. [image: black-and-white hedgehog]

Perhaps this is clearer with some colour:

> [image: colourful hedgehog]

Assuming ‘every part of the drawing’ includes the gaps in the given curved lines, they can be explained as

> pupils. The hedgehog has its left eye trained on its spine. With but a single one remaining, this is an appropriate level of caution.

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't been selected as the correct answer!